# What happens to the List content?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, scope

I have a list, defined as a global in the base class:

```
private List<Object> progObjs;
```

In the constructor of a derived class I have:

```
Object newObj = new Object();

this.progObjs = new List<Object>();
this.progObjs.Add(newObj);
```

Adding a break point after this shows that the object has gone into the list, and the list is of now `Count = 1`.

However, in another function in the class, I attempt to use the first object in the list (i.e. `progObjs[0]`), but it throws a `NullReferenceException` and the list is actually `Count = 0`, even though I haven't removed the object from the list myself.

What has happened to the object in my list?

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: How are you calling it in the other function?

Comment: If the progObjs field is private in the base class, the constructor of the derived class shouldn't have access to it. I suppose your sample code is not the real code? (Since the compiler should have generated an error).

Comment: Between the insertion and the point of failure, either something removed the element or replaced `progObjs` with a new List. Another possibility is that the other code is accessing a different `progObjs`. Without some additional context, it's difficult to offer more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

I'm working with XNA, and the base class's Initialize method was resetting the list after the derrived class defined it.